# How to generate PDF from a complex web page requiring authentication?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

My ASP.NET Web Forms app generates a report, via a fairly complicated process: authentication, ViewState, and asynchronous retrieval of data.

I would like to give the user the option of downloading the report they are viewing as a PDF file. I'd prefer to convert the HTML to PDF, so the two cannot get out of sync due to incremental changes.

I can find .NET components which can point to a Url and generate PDF, but I'm not sure how this will work on my complex reports. Should I grab the Viewstate and Auth cookies from the user's request and pass them through the PDF generator? I could get all the settings into the Url if needed, eliminating ViewState.

Anyone have experience with this sort of setup? Suggested software?

Answer (score 0):

you could save to disk and pass the HTML page you're sending to the client to a tool such as `wkhtml2pdf` (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) and use XHR to periodically check if the file was rendered, if so provide a download link.